# MVVM WPF screencasts?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have just changed my job, and I need to learn MVVM pattern deeply.

What are the best screencasts of using MVVM pattern for WPF?
What can you recommend for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's really old, but it's outstanding.  I used this over 2 yrs ago to first begin learning MVVM

[Lab49's Jason Dolinger on MVVM with WPF](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

Comment: This site is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one on Channel 9

[MVVM, a WPF UI Design Pattern](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Continuum/MVVM)